# Excel VBA to resize an image to fit in the visible grid

Tags: excel, vba, image, resize

I am trying to write a macro that resizes a shape (an image) to fit into the visible area of the active window. For context, I am building a randomized image slideshow and this code is being run immediately after the image is opened. This is done repeatedly for multiple images within a directory.

The code I have (below) works well for many images, but for about half of those I have tested the height of the image ends up exceeding the viewing area (the grid). I have tried comparing the image height to ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Height, ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VisibleRange.Height, ActiveWindow.Height, and ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Rows.Height, but all of these have resulted in images cut off at the bottom. Additionally, the code should be setting the images at the top-left, but for many images, it is centering them horizontally within the window.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ResizeShape()
    Dim visRange As Range
    Dim areaHeight As Double
    Dim areaWidth As Double
    
    
    areaHeight = ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VisibleRange.Height
    areaWidth = ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VisibleRange.Width
    
    'myshape is a module-level shape object
    If myShape Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No Image!"
    
    myShape.Height = areaHeight
    
    If myShape.Width > areaWidth Then myShape.Width = areaWidth
    
    
    myShape.Top = 0
    myShape.Left = 0
        
End Sub
```